# Javascript AJAX Click event sometimes not working in Android native browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, android-browser

While testing my application with different devices I found one weird problem in android browser in android phones.

I have almost same design for PC and and mobile, in PC and in iPhone and mobile Chrome browser its working fine.

```
<a type="cart_type" onclick="ajax_submit_for_new_order_session(81, true); 
return false;" id="81" href="javascript:void(0)">
<i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></a>
```

Above is the code for my anchor tag, When I click on this anchor tag sometimes its calling the specified method and sometimes its not.

I am totally confused and scratching my head from so long for finding the issue but no luck.

Is there any problem with onclick in mobile devices?

Comment: Have you tried using touch events instead?

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu can we write touch events inline? like I did above.

Comment: You could try something like: "ontouchmove", "ontouchstart", "ontouchend"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by updating the jQuery version to 1.11 earlier I am using 1.8

instead of using `onclick` now I am using `touchstart` or `mousedown`

this Solves the problem in all devices..

Its not problem with the code.. the delay taking by the browser is sometimes about 5 sec.